# Problem with canceling a jquery animation with a cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cookie

I'd like to make a jquery animation run only once per session with a cookie. I've sort of figured out how to do this with Klaus Hartl’s cookie plugin, but, when the page is called the second time, the elements flash. I'm under the impression that $.fx.off is supposed to make jquery jump to the end state of the animation, but, the elements flash briefly, it's like instead of just jumping to the end state, it just plays through the animation really quickly. The cookie will drop out when the browser is quit, and then the animation will play again--that's what I want to have happen. I just want the animation to play once per session. I can find some good tutorials online about how to make a cookie switch CSS states, but I want something that will simply prevent the jquery animation from running so that the end state is visible.

Here's my test page:

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-cookies-04.html

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var welcome=$.cookie('welcome'); if(welcome == 'ran') {$.fx.off = !$.fx.off;}; 
</script>


<!--slider-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){$(".imwpj")
.animate({"top": "+=200px"}, 0)
.fadeIn(2000).delay(200).animate({"top": "+=295px"}, 1100, function() {
$('#sub-fader').fadeIn(1500); });
$.cookie('welcome', 'ran');
}); 
</script>
```

Any thoughts would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var welcome=$.cookie('welcome'); 
 $(window).load(function(){
  if(welcome != 'ran') {
     $(".imwpj")
     .animate({"top": "+=200px"}, 0) // this is not necessary, you can use css("top", "200px")
     .fadeIn(2000).delay(200).animate({"top": "+=295px"}, 1100, function() {
     $('#sub-fader').fadeIn(1500); });
     $.cookie('welcome', 'ran');
  } else {
     $(".imwpj").css("top", "495px");
     $("#sub-fader").css("display", "block");  //or .show();
  }
 });
```

why not like this?

Comment: Okay, interesting! It definitely stopped the animation with that cookie--but what part of your code is telling things to stop exactly?

Comment: ...what I need to do now is to display the final state of the whole animation if the cookie gives the "ran" value... Any insight into that would be great! As it is now after installing your code, I get an empty background which is promising, as I know the animation is stopped.

Comment: try my update, i added a simple else method where to immediatally do what you need. Btw. Is there any reason, why the element "imwpj" is twice on the page?

Comment: I've got it on there twice because it will be hidden by #sub-fader when it fades in... (I bet there's a better way!) Thank you for your help--I'll try this now.

Comment: ok, but with your animation function you move both items :) Just put one away

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Luke--much appreciated. Here's that page with your code--http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-cookies-09.html  As you can see, I've created a separate DIV for that moving animation. You rock!

Comment: I just took that page down--here is the one with the code: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index.html

Comment: Luke's code still in effect--this time with a more complicated animation.