# jquery stop animation when completed

Tags: jquery

I've looked around and can't find my problem solved. Here it is...
When my page loads I have a div animate into the page horizontally from the left. The div animates from a negative to 0. Cool, exactly what I want it to do.

The problem is, I don't want the div to animate when a new link is clicked and loads another page. I figured I'ld create an if statement that says, when div equals 0 stop animation or keep it's original value of 0. Having the animate() in the beginning of the code plays out every time the page reloads when a link is clicked. How do I go about fixing this?

```
// Set new postion of sideBarNavigation to animate into container screen
var newSbnXPosition = $(".slideContainer").css({"top": "0em" , "left": "-14.3125em"});
//alert(newSbnXPosition.position().left);

(newSbnXPosition).animate({left: "0"}, "slow", function() {
    console.log("imagesContainer = " + $(".imagesContainer").position().left);
    if (newSbnXPosition.position().left === 0) {
            console.log("statment is true remove animation");
            //$(".slideContainer").css({"top": "0em" , "left": "0em"});
            //newSbnXPosition.position().left = 0;

    }
});
```

Comment: if you reload another page (or the very same page again), then the whole script will run again. you can use a cookie, for example, to make the browser remember that the animation was already shown to the current user.

Comment: @szajmon Yes, that's what I was finding to be the problem. You have a link on creating cookies by any chance? I'm going to do a search as well.

Comment: I think I found some good info on cookies...I'll be back to score the answer if all goes well, which it should.

Comment: I found this that might be helpful. I can't mess with it right now. Be back to update. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856469/problem-with-canceling-a-jquery-animation-with-a-cookie

Comment: @szajmon if you would of displayed as an answer I would of checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, use this cookie plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Set a cookie like this:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

Check if a cookie exists like this:

```
$.cookie("example");
```

Delete cookies like this:

```
$.cookie("example", null);
```